# How to send text to other user in same app

Tags: android

Guys.. I am developing an app based on 20 questions concept. i need to send Question as text to other user and other user will respond to that Question in yes or No by pressing yes No button.. This must be online app and questions and answers history will be stored in database on server.. kindly help me i have no clue how to do this this is my final year project my whole degree depends on it.. any suggestions any API any builtin functions??

```
broadcast()
```

will work or not?

Comment: You need a whole client server setup with a set of webservice queries.  This question is way too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GCM` for this purpose, send `notification` from first user and when you receive notification on other device show some dialog according to your need(with Yes/No).

OnClick of yes/no you can again send notification to first user which will show status of whether user have clicked on yes or no.

You need to maintain notification type, like what kind of notification message you have sent and manage it when you receive notification on a device.

There are so many alternatives for GCM.

1. [urbanairship](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html)
2. [xtify](http://developer.xtify.com/login.action;jsessionid=67AD904F95A2005ED070578B24553C86?os_destination=%2Fdisplay%2Fsupport%2FXtify%2BDeveloper%2BDocumentation%2BSite)
3. [pushlets](http://www.pushlets.com/)
4. [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/)

Yes it's too broad to answer your question as mentioned by **Gabe Sechan**, i have just answered some part of your question.

Comment: thanx mate for you help but i have already submitted my document to my evaluators.. i can not use notification... my requirement is to show Question text in Large text-box on other users screen

Comment: you can implement any client-server mechanism, when you can pass information to other users.